# WinJS.Namespace defined methods not accessible

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I have a navigation app. In the page Control corresponding js files are present. I want to access an external js file which is in the project js folder. I have specified in

commonFunctions.js

```
WinJS.Namespace.define(

'commonFunctions', {

        authenticate: authenticate

    });
```

Now when accessing the method in the PageControl's js (page2.js) file

commonFunctions.authenticate();

it gives an error:

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'commonFunctions' is undefined

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Is this the right way to do this? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Could you include the code where you are calling your objects function.

Comment: (function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/configScreen/configScreen.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            
           commonFunctions.authenticate();
        },

        unload: function () {
                   }

    
    });}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is either that you have not referenced your script file inside the page you are loading or you have not wrapped your `commonFunctions` object in a function.

I tried this:
script.js

```
(function () {
    WinJS.Namespace.define("CommonObject", {
        auth: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });
}());
```

default.js

```
    app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
                // your application here.
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
                // Restore application state here.
            }

            if (app.sessionState.history) {
                nav.history = app.sessionState.history;
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function () {
                var test = CommonObject.auth(); // Comes out true and no exceptions
                if (nav.location) {
                    nav.history.current.initialPlaceholder = true;
                    return nav.navigate(nav.location, nav.state);
                } else {
                    return nav.navigate(Application.navigator.home);
                }
            }));
        }
    });
```

default.html

```
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've done same and added the script reference also. <script src="/js/commonFunctions.js"></script>  And in the navigated page I have the following: 
(function () {"use strict";                                         WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/configScreen/configScreen.html", {
ready: function (element, options) {commonFunctions.authenticate();
}});
WinJS.Namespace.define('Settings', {saveSettings: saveSettings});
function saveSettings() {"use strict";commonFunctions.authenticate();}still the same error 0x800a1391-JavaScript runtime rror:'commonFunctions' undefined

Comment: @user1733839 See if the function is correctly called in your default.html and if it is then the script is not correctly loaded in the page you're navigating to.

Comment: I have all these in place. Also when the app is running the DOM Explorer shows the commonFunctions.js file loaded. I also tried to access the same method from the default.js file (i.e. not from the navigated file) it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @user1733839 Are you using the RTM versions of both visual studio and Windows 8?

Comment: Yes, now it is working. There was a mistake in my code. (function () {
    WinJS.Namespace.define("CommonObject", {
        auth: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });
}()); The Code was not enclosed in the function (anonymus block ();) Hence I was not able to access the method. Thanks Konstantin :)